# change color per day at an event a few days FULLCALENDAR

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm using `fullcalendar` to show events from database but on the same event I want to some days red(danger) and some days blue(default) in accordance with a fields on database.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. You can specify color in your events to change color. Example:

```
  [
    [
        title: Red,
        color: #DC143C
    ],
    [
        title: Blue,
        color: #00FFFF
    ]
]
```

You can also change it dynamically using eventRender callback as following example:

```
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
                if(event.title=="Red")
                    element.css('background-color', '#DC143C');
                if(event.title=="Blue")
                    element.css('background-color', '#00FFFF');
```

}